# How to access database connection and base url in child folder?

Tags: php

I am working on XYZ project. In that project having admin, assets, class, controller, core folder and some .php files. In core folder having config.php and database.php files.

Here's config.php code:

```
<?php 
include ("core/database.php");

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include ('class/'.$class_name . '.php');
});

?>
```

and database.php code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/XYZ/');
class database{
    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;

    protected function connect(){
        $this->servername = 'localhost';
        $this->username = 'root';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->dbname = 'xyz';
        $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
        return $conn;
        
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        echo "Connected successfully";
    }

}
?>
```

Here's index.php code:

```
<?php
include("core/config.php");
echo BASE_URL;
exit();
?>
```

In that page i got BASE_URL in defined in database.php

But when i try to get same BASE_URL in admin->index.php got some error following:

```
Warning: include(core/database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\core\config.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'core/database.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\core\config.php on line 3

Notice: Use of undefined constant BASE_URL - assumed 'BASE_URL' in C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\admin\index.php on line 3
BASE_URL
```

So, My query is how to access databse connection and BASE_URL in admin->index.php

@rajeev answer i got database connection and BASE_URL in admin->index.php

But i have one more query

In class folder having Test.php file the code is below:

```
<?php
class Test extends Database{
    function __construct(){
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $date = date("y-m-d H:i:s");
        $this->get_date = $date;
    }   

    public function test(){
        return $this->get_date; 
    }
}
?>
```

This class i want access in admin->index.php file but get error below

```
Warning: include(class/Test.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\technical\core\config.php on line 6

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'class/Test.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\technical\core\config.php on line 6

Fatal error: Class 'Test' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\technical\admin\index.php on line 5
```

and i tried code in admin->index.php

```
<?php
include("../core/config.php");

$testClass = new Test();
echo $testClass->test();
?>
```

Comment: change the line include ("core/database.php") to include ("database.php"); in config.php file

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**getcwd**"(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) function to gets the current working directory. If the "class" folder isn't accessible in the current working directory, you will have to change your include path in the "config.php" file.

Comment: After change the line include ("core/database.php") to include ("database.php"); in config.php file i got BASE_URL in admin->index.php, but i can't class->Test.php file. I got following error: Warning: include(class/Test.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\technical\core\config.php on line 6

Comment: Try to use the chdir for change your working folder.